# Calculated column problem from Multiple lines of text

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I need to add calculated column (or something else) to my list which can discover and write, if is something in column of "multiple lines of text" within the bounds of this list.

I can do it with Calculated column for "**Single line of text**", or **date** , etc.

I've used formula: 
`=IF([Column1]>0,"OK")`

and it works, but I can't do it for columnt "**multiple lines of text**". 
I need some idea, how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are either:

- Create a Workflow starting on Item added/changed
- Create a (Remote) Event Receiver associated with ItemAdded and ItemUpdated
- Put JavaScript into the New/Edit form

Comment: Which kind of Workflow? Where I must put JavaScript and which JavaScript? Thanks for you instruction

Comment: You can create a SharePoint workflow in either SharePoint Designer or Visual studio. For the JavaScript solution, which I will only recommend if you can't do any of the "real" solutions, you would need to create your "calculated" field as an ordinary field, disable inline editing in all views and then customize the two forms to hide the "calculated" field and update it before submit